# ClassLoader.getResource() doesn't work for the icon files in a jar. The icons need to be present in the folder containing jar

Tags: java, icons

I'm working on a Java program that uses icon files. The icons are stored in a folder `Icons` in `/src`. The code to access an icon is

> image1 = new ImageIcon(Control.PrimaryGameFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Icons/openFile.gif"));

The program runs properly in Eclipse. But when I export its runnable jar to a folder `abc`, then it needs the `Icons` folder to be present in `abc`. If I place the jar alone at a place, it doesn't load the icons. What changes are to be made to the code, for the jar to find the icon files in itself and not in the folder it is in?

Comment: Have you confirmed the presence of an Icons folder inside the .jar itself?

Comment: yes.. it is there in the jar when I checked its contents

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass.getResource("Icons/openFile.gif");
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: I tried this and with this it doesn't work even after I place the Icons in "abc" so I added getClassLoader.